# How to draw the NP "so little" in "He said so little" in a tree diagram?

Tags: syntax-trees, x-bar-theory, dependency-grammar, determiners

> *He said so little.*

includes the NP *so little*, which doesn't include any noun.

In the X-bar theory style tree diagram, how do you go about describing the NP? Do you have N' below the NP? Do you have N below N'?

This is of course assuming that you don't follow the DP hypothesis, under which it'd be easy to draw the DP *so little*.

Comment: No need to close this one: It contains a concrete question.

Comment: Call the NPs D-bars, and mark _so little_ as the D that's projected.

Comment: @jlawler If you're suggesting that I use the DP hypothesis, my question is presented in case the DP hypothesis is not adopted.

Comment: If you wait until a syntactic hypothesis is adopted, you'll have a long wait. That was the point behind McCawley's title _Thirty Million Theories of Syntax_; he was referring to al the possible theories depending on one or another unsettled hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possibilities for the X-bar analysis of the phrase *so little*. A central choice one has to make concerns viewing *little* as an adjective or as a derived noun, that is, as a noun derived from an adjective. My favored analysis would be to view it as the latter. Given this decision, the next decision one has to make concerns the status of *so*: should it be viewed as an adjunct or as a specifier?  Viewing it as an adjunct might result in the following X-bar analysis:

[image]

Viewing it as a specifier instead might motivate the next analysis:

[image]

Concerning the first major decision mentioned above, the analysis would look much different if one chooses to view *little* as a normal adjective. In such a case, one would probably want to assume noun ellipsis, that is, that the noun has been elided. Such an approach might produce the following analysis, where a special symbol is used to indicate an elided noun:

[image]

For me, the difficulty with this analysis is that it is not clear what the noun is that one would understand to have been elided.

The question states that the analysis would be straightforward if the DP-analysis of nominal groups were assumed instead of the NP-analysis. I do not see why that should be the case. The DP-analysis adds an additional category to it all, opening the door to a more layered analyses, with additional projections. That means even more decisions become necessary.

Finally, let me express my personal view about X-bar analyses. I think they are not well motivated linguistically. They are in general overly complex and thus subject to great variation, even among experts. In this regard, consider the simplicity of a dependency grammar (DG) analysis of the sentence:

[image]

DG assumes a strict one-to-one correspondence of atomic units of syntax (i.e. words) to nodes in the syntax tree. This principle limits the potential analyses greatly. Dependency grammarians could hardly disagree about the analysis of a simple phrase such as *so little*.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the DP analysis is more layered, but once you draw the DP tree of _so little_, you'll see what I mean. And I'd go for the ellipted noun tree over calling _little_ a noun, which I don't know how to justify when it's being modified by the adverb _so_.

Comment: Happy to help. But if a noun has been elided, then what is that noun? When talking about N-ellipsis (also called NP-ellipsis), both versions are typically possible. In this regard, consider the sentence "You took the first train, and I took the second" as compared to the sentence "You took the first train, and I took the second train". Adding the noun is hardly possible in the case of "so little", e.g. "He said so little" vs. "?He said so little stuff." The noun I've added, i.e. "stuff", does not fit well, yet it is the best I can do.

Comment: I totally agree with you that adding a noun results in a rather awkward NP with "so little". Still, calling _little_ a noun and trying to figure out how to explain the adverb _so_ modifies a noun is I think way more awkward.

Comment: The difficulty seems to arise from the perceived necessity to view "little" as an adjective or a noun. In this case, it does not fit well into either category. A more flexible approach might be warranted, one that grants "little" a unique category status in this case. Consider gerunds in this regard, a category that is situated between verb and noun, e.g. "Trump saying that was ridiculous". The gerund "saying" does not qualify entirely as a verb because it appears where a noun generally appears. Yet it is not a entirely a noun, for it takes the dependents of a transitive verb.

Comment: I think your example is a bit different for I'd consider 'saying' a full-fledged verb, never a noun. A non-finite verb is a full-fledged verb. What's noun-y is not 'saying' itself but the entire phrase 'Trump saying that'. To be exact, even calling the entire phrase noun-y is not accurate, because it's not noun that functions as subject, it's an NP.

Comment: But "saying" can take a determiner, a clear indicator of a noun, e.g. "His saying that was ridiculous". Would saying as a verb in this case also?

Comment: Yes, I'd consider it as a verb too. If it were a noun, you wouldn't be able to explain how the pronoun 'that' could be complement of a noun. No noun I know of can take a pronoun as complement. In fact, 'His' is not a determiner because you can use 'him' instead of 'his' in the same construction, where the former is definitely not a determiner: _Him saying that was ridiculous_

Comment: I prefer to acknowledge a unique category, one that behaves as a noun with respect to its head and as a noun or verb with respect to its dependents. The fact that the pronoun *that* can replace the whole is in line with *saying* being a noun: *His saying that was ridiculous* --> *That was ridiculous*. The fact that *his* can introduce *saying* is consistent with *saying* as a noun with respect one of its dependents, and the fact that *that* can appear as complement of *saying* is consistent with *saying* as a verb with respect with its other dependent.

Comment: Pronouns can replace not only NPs but a clause, finite or non-finite. _That he said that was ridiculous_ --> _That was ridiculous._ So just because the latter works doesn't mean that _Him saying that_ was a prototypical NP.

Comment: OK, let me try drawing attention to a related type of data. Prepositions generally take nominal dependents. They can take a gerund dependent, e.g. *We are relying on his telling the truth*. They cannot take verb dependents, e.g. **We are relying on him tell the truth*, **We are relying on him to tell the truth*, **We are relying on he tells the truth*. To address this behavior, one needs to acknowledge that gerunds are not verbs in one crucial respect, but rather they are like nouns in that respect.

Comment: Are you sure _We are relying on him to tell the truth_ doesn't work for you? I find it well formed. In fact, I'd prefer that one over _We are relying on his/him telling the truth_.

Comment: I see, yes. I think the reading you indicate is indeed available. But that reading is not the one intended. I intended the reading where he is necessarily the one telling the truth. The reading you suggest could be such that we are relying on him so that we (or someone else) can tell the truth.  All that can be put aside, though, because the particle *to* is the head of *to tell the truth*, not the verb *tell*. So my point still stands, a verb cannot be a direct dependent of a preposition, ergo gerunds must not be verbs in that sense.

Comment: I'm rather surprised at your interpretation. Regardless of the form of the verb tell, be it V-ing, to-infinitive, or bare infinitive, I think the meaning of this particular sentence is that he is the one telling the truth, not we or someone else. That said, there could be other sentences where the semantic subject of 'to tell the truth' is not the object of 'rely on' but the subject of the sentence, but I don't think this particular sentence is such a sentence.